# Custom aliases for all fields with GROUP BY ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have such tables:

```
Group    - combination of TypeId and ZoneId   

ID   TypeID          ZoneID
--     --                --
1     1                  1 
2     1                  2       
3     2                  1
4     2                  2
5     2                  3
6     3                  3

Object

ID    GroupId
--       --
1         1
2         1
3         2
4         3
5         3
6         3
```

I want to build a query for grouping all these tables by TypeId and ZoneId, with number of objects which have specific combination of these field:

```
ResultTable

TypeId   ZoneId          Number of objects
--         --                 --
1          1                  2 
1          2                  1       
2          1                  3
2          2                  1
2          3                  0
3          3                  0
```

Query for this:

```
SELECT
  group.TypeId,
  group.ZoneId, 
  COUNT(obj.ID) as NumberOfObjects
  FROM[Group] group
  JOIN[Object] obj on obj.GroupID = group.ID 
  GROUP BY group.TypeId, group.ZoneId ORDER BY  group.TypeId
```

But! I want to add summarize row after each group, and make it like:

```
ResultTableWithSummary

TypeId   ZoneId          Number of objects
--         --                 --
1          1                  2 
1          2                  1   
Summary   (empty field)       3 
2          1                  3
2          2                  1
2          3                  0
Summary   (empty field)       4
3          3                  0
Summary    (empty field)      0
```

The problem is that I can use GROUP BY ROLLUP(group.TypeId, group.ZoneId):

```
TypeId   ZoneId          Number of objects
--         --                 --
1          1                  2 
1          2                  1   
1         null                3 
2          1                  3
2          2                  1
2          3                  0
2          null               4
3          3                  0
3          null               0
```

but I cannot or don't know how to change not-null group.TypeId in summary rows with "Summary".
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is `coalesce()`, but you need to be sure the types match:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), group.TypeId, 'Summary') as TypeId,
. . .
```

This is not the most general method, because it does not handle real `NULL` values in the `GROUP BY` keys.  That doesn't seem to be an issue in this case.  If it were, you could use a `CASE` expression with `GROUPING()`.

EDIT:

For your particular variant (which I find strange), you can use:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN group.TypeId IS NULL OR group.ZoneID IS NULL
             THEN 'Summary' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), group.TypeId)
        END) as TypeId,
. . .
```

In practice, I would use something similar to the `COALESCE()` in both columns, so I don't lose the information on what the summary is for.

Comment: Upvoted for the [grouping()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql).

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot use COALESCE for this (and this is the problem) - with rollup group.TypeId is always not null, but group.ZoneId is null.